# How to change text height in pdfbox

Tags: pdfbox

PDFBOX / JSF

Im trying to change the ***font height*** of a given text. I know how to change the fontsize only.

```
PDPageContentStream contentStreambc = new PDPageContentStream(doc1, page, true, true);
contentStreambc.setFont( fonta, 16 );

contentStreambc.beginText();
contentStreambc.moveTextPositionByAmount(200, 320);
contentStreambc.drawString( "abcdef");
contentStreambc.endText();
contentStreambc.close();
```

The code works fine. But How I change the font height ?

thanks in advance stack members.

Comment: *font height / fontsize* - what exactly do you mean by *font height* in contrast to *font size*? Do you want to stretch the letters upwards while keeping their width? Or something else entirely?

Comment: I need to increase the font height while keeping the same font size and width @mkl

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need something like this

[image]

you can create it with this code:

```java
PDRectangle rec = new PDRectangle(220, 70);
PDDocument document = null;
document = new PDDocument();

PDPage page = new PDPage(rec);
document.addPage(page);

PDPageContentStream content = new PDPageContentStream(document, page, true, true);

content.beginText();
content.moveTextPositionByAmount(7, 55);
content.setFont(PDType1Font.HELVETICA, 12);
content.drawString("Normal text (size 12)");
content.setTextMatrix(1, 0, 0, 1.5f, 7, 30);
content.drawString("Stretched text (size 12, factor 1.5)");
content.setTextMatrix(1, 0, 0, 2f, 7, 5);
content.drawString("Stretched text (size 12, factor 2)");
content.endText();

content.close();

document.save("SimplePdfStretchedText.pdf");
```

The code stretches the text by setting the text matrix accordingly; for details cf. chapter 9 of the PDF specification [ISO 32000-1](https://adobe.com/go/pdfreference).

**PS:** As you mention bar codes in a comment to another answer, this should indeed allow you to make higher bar codes while keeping the distances.

Comment: Thats exactly what I needed it. Worked successfull @mkl. thank you so much guys.